# How to rewrite all same files to sites in root via SSH?

Tags: ssh, root

I have a hundred same sites in my root directory i want to modify one page and i must rewrite all sites , is there any easy way to modify them.

You can think as this, you have VPS root server and you set up 100 joomla in your server. They have different databases but all of them are same files.

And you must change footer.php file so what will you do?

You must open root and replace the footer file to all sites one by one.

And so it is a hard way. There must be easy way via SSH or Php codes, etc..

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the editor of your choice and batch process all the files.

e.g. on Windows, mount the folder as a network drive, open all footer.php files in Notepad++ and do a search and replace on all open files.

e.g. on the Unix command line, use `find` (maybe `xargs`) and `sed` or `vim -c`. alternatively to something like the Windows approach with e.g. Sublime text or any other editor.